# Pokemon Go paw glitch

Tags: pokemon-go, android

When I'm playing Pokemon Go, I can see the Pokemon just fine. It's just that the nearby Pokemon are always the same no matter how far away I go or if I catch them—the amount of paws is always 3. Once I restart the game, the Pokemon change, but the paw amount is always 3.

Please help

I have the Motog3 Plus phone B.T.W

I've tried every GPS fixing solution I could find and re-downloading the app and restarting phone.

Comment: I believe this is a new bug with the recent update as I noticed this happening today as well. No matter how close or far from them they are always 3 paw marks even when they are showing on the screen for me to catch.

Answer (score 5):

I noticed this too. It could be a bug in the game that causes the GPS to be inaccurate with the paw prints. A Growlithe showed up near me, allowing me to capture it, but my grid says 3 paw prints for all the 9 Pokemon, even with the white pokeball loading symbol gone (done loading). Also, grass/leaf patches don't always mean there is a Pokemon. I ran far to a rustling patch before, but all the Pokemon on my grid were 3 paws away. [More info on rustling leaves](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/272709/118250)

Although I believe this is an unintentional bug by Niantic, I would recommend searching primarily for just 2 and 1 paw print Pokemon if it shows up. The 3 paw prints seem buggy, even though it means 150 meters to 200 meters within range according to this answer: [Step Distance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/272615/118250)
Try to go with a group a friends so that you cover more area and find Pokemon more easily. In addition, you can try going toward leaf patches for a slightly higher chance of an encounter.

EDIT: As of now, I have iPhone 6s with version 1.0.2 in the app store of Pokemon Go. The in-game version says 0.29.2

Source: My experience