# Does leveling up increase your range?

Tags: pokemon-go

There is a large circle around you which appears to be a limit on how close you can catch pokemon, and how close you have to be to interact with pokestops/gyms. I heard a rumor that the size of this circle increases as  you level up, is this true?

On the other hand I've also caught pokemon that were standing just outside the circle...

Comment: I haven't seen it increase up to level 15, and you can catch Pokemon outside of the range, as long as they're on your screen, you just can't interact with gyms or Poke-Stops outside of it

Comment: Some Pokemon can be caught outside the circle sometimes, it tends to be kinda random I've seen. But I've never seen the circle increase in size with levels.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it doesn't increase your range. The circle's range is 40 meters. Source is from experience, as well as that being the range in Ingress.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't 50 meters? Each paw print is 50 so it would seem more logical that they'd use the same distance for the circle http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272531/what-do-these-steps-in-pok%C3%A9mon-go-mean

Comment: I went and checked the TheSilphRoad subreddit for further investigation, and the agreed on number there is 40 meters as well. The game isn't very consistent overall anyways, so I wouldn't try to base the stats for one feature on those of another.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you guys are talking about. When I was around level 8 There was a Pokéstop that I HAD to cross the street to the median to get. I'm level 15 now and I was on the COMPLETE OPPOSITE SIDE of the road and could hit it.

Comment: While I've experienced the same thing, I highly suspect this is just a side effect of GPS inaccuracy/variation.