# Why are no paw prints displayed?

Tags: pokemon-go

So I started playing Pokemon Go and after some research I realized that there should be paw prints in the **Sightings Menu** at the bottom-right. However, there are never paws displayed for any pokemon. I've never seen any paws, and the Pokemon are obviously not nearby at all as I can't see them. Is there a fix to this?

Comment: The proximity paw prints were removed completely a while ago. See: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/272615/145980

Comment: @MageXy they had to make it harder didn't they...

Comment: @MageXy is there still a way to track down Pokemon?

Comment: Yes. Walk in a random direction and hope you encounter it. If the Pokemon disappears from your "nearby" list, you either walked too far or in the entirely wrong direction. Other than that, no.

Comment: Or someone catched it.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Pokemon do not disappear if someone else catches them. They only disappear for you once you catch them, or once their spawn timer runs out.

Comment: @MageXy or if you fail to catch them and run away

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no, Niantic updated the game removing the footsteps. You just have to go around and hunt down the Pokemon. All we can do is hope they bring it back.

Comment: Niantic is AB testing a new way of finding nearby pokemon, that makes it easier to locate pokemon than with paw prints. To be fair, considering the number of people that used third-party apps to locate pokemon, paw prints were widely considered to not be useful enough.